# vb.net - tab control?

Tags: vb.net, winforms, tabcontrol

I have a Tab Control on a Winform. I want to add another page but I want it to appear between the current page 1 and page 2, basically I want to insert it. How can I do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are looking to do this from the deseigner:

- Under the TabControl Properties,
  select TabPages. This will bring up
  the tab pages dialog.
- Click the Add button. Should add a
  new tab page at the end.
- Use the arrows to move the page to
  the position required.

If you wish to do this from code:

Have a look at [TabControl.TabPages.Insert](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.tabcontrol.tabpagecollection.insert.aspx)

> Inserts a tab page into the collection
>   at the specified index.